# Code formatting (grave accents) doesn't work properly in comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting, markdown

If we have some inline code, marked up with grave accents, it works properly *in the question body*, even when there's something right after the accent:

Examples:
I want to find `N`th character in a string.
Don't use `Collection`s, those fancy `Collection`s just suck.
I want to use `N`th `N` in my code.

But, if we have exactly same thing in a comment, the formatting falls apart (see the comments).

Comment: I want to find `N`th character in a string.

Comment: Don't use `Collection`s, those fancy `Collection`s just suck.

Comment: I'm going to bet 100 reputation on **`[status-by-design]`**

Comment: I want to use `N`th `N` in my code.

Comment: @Justin: I believe it's not. Look at the third example, does feel like a bug, doesn't it?

Comment: @GSerg, well, it is sub-optimal performance.  But I doubt they will look into it any more...

Comment: @Justin, you need'nt bet because we've been through this several times already..

Comment: @Justin: Can I have your 100 rep?

Comment: I lose...It's a good thing we didn't shake on it.

Comment: @jjnguy It would appear it's now `status-completed`.

Comment: @GSerg it does indeed. I've re-tagged it. Thanks.

Answer (score -6):

We only support a subset of markdown in comments, and the rules are stricter about what will and won't work.

Comment: Are you sure it's not **`[status-by-design]`** ?  Otherwise I lose a bet... `:P`  And declining a bug doesn't make as much sense as declaring it by-design.